# jqgrid inline editing using actions - not able to show error messsage

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jqgrid

I am using inline editing of jQgrid with edit action button, but **aftersavefunc** not working. what is the right way to do it ?

I want restore the row and show error message when I receive from server : **{"success":false,"id":null,"message":"You can not do that"}**

following is my code:

```
 angular.element(document).ready(function () {

    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: $scope.listResellerUser,
        mtype: "POST",
        colModel: [
            { label:'Full Name', name: 'fullname' },
            { label: 'User Name', name: 'username' },
            { label: 'User Id', name: 'userId', hidden: true, key:true },
            { label: 'Email', name: 'email' },
            { label: 'User Level', name:'roleId', index:'roleId', edittype:'select', editable:true, align:'center', formatter:'select', 
                editoptions:{value:setRoleDropdown()
            }},
            {name:'Actions',index:'Actions',width:55,align:'center',sortable:false,search: false,formatter:'actions',
                 formatoptions:{
                     keys: true, // we want use [Enter] key to save the row and [Esc] to cancel editing.
                     delbutton:false,
                 }}

        ],
        editurl: "/myreseller/changeuserrole",
        styleUI : 'Bootstrap',
        page: 1,
        autowidth: true,
        height: 250,
        rowNum: 20,
        scrollPopUp:true,
        scrollLeftOffset: "83%",
        viewrecords: true,
        scroll: 1, // set the scroll property to 1 to enable paging with scrollbar - virtual loading of records
        emptyrecords: 'Scroll to bottom to retrieve new page', // the message will be displayed at the bottom 
        pager: "#jqGridPager",
        editParams: {
            "aftersavefunc": function (rowid, response, options) {
                alert("row with rowid=" + rowid + " is successfuly modified.");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's important to include the information about the version of jqGrid, which you use (or which you can use) and the fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) in the text of your question.

I develop free jqGrid fork, which supports Bootstrap too (see [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#bootstrap)). Thus I can't help you in specific problems of Guriddo jqGrid JS. It seems to me, but you use non-existing option `editParams`. Free jqGrid allows to specify common inline editing options via `inlineEditing` option (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods)). If you stay by commercial Guriddo jqGrid JS, then you probably have to specify the callback functions of the `formatter:'actions'` inside of `formatoptions` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) of `onSuccess`, `onError`, `afterSave` and other callbacks).

Moreover the callback `aftersavefunc` seems to be wrong choice in your case. It will be called **after** processing of the server response. Every response from `editurl` with successful HTTP status code will be interpreted as success and the changes (wrong changed) will be saved in the grid. One can solve the problem either by usage `errorfunc` callback and returning some error HTTP status code (>=400) or by usage `successfunc` callback, which allows to process the content of the server response and return `[false, "error text"]` or `[true]` depend on the content of the server response. It seems to me that it's what you need.